# How to give over right (table) permission in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. I tried to modify the table. But it not allowing to update.

How to give UPDATE permission in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out:

[Giving and removing permissions in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1138)

or any other decent SQL Server web site, or just google for it! There's tons of sites and books out there that will show you how to do this in great detail....

Basically, someone with the necessary permissions needs to do a

```
GRANT UPDATE ON (your table name) TO (your user name)
```

and that's about it. Of course, you may also need SELECT, INSERT and other permissions.....

Answer (score 2):

You need to [grant access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx) to the table for your specific user/role, e.g.

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on table to user
```

This will allow you to change and select data within the table.  To modify the table itself (add/remove columns etc.) you will want:

```
grant create, alter, drop on table to user
```