# Can we deny delete from specific tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to deny delete permissions for set of tables, for a particular user in sql server 2008 .i want that a user can not delete data from some tables in a database , do not want to use instead of trigger for particular table cause i have 90 tables ??

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988741/how-to-give-over-right-table-permission-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely!

```
DENY DELETE ON (YourTableNameHere) TO YourUserNameHere
```

See [the wonderful and extensive MSDN Books Online docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx) for more details!

If you want to deny the `DELETE` permission on **all** tables in a database, you can use:

```
DENY DELETE TO YourUserNameHere
```

Or if you've structured your database in such a way that the tables are grouped in **schematas**, then you can also deny a user from a specific schema.

If you haven't grouped your 90 tables into a separate schema (or two, three schematas), then there's **no easy, magical way** to apply a permission to 90 tables at once. It's either **all tables**, a specific schema, or a specific database object (like a table) per `DENY` statement.

**Update:** you can always use the system catalog views to generate those `DENY` statements for you, and then use those that you need:

```
SELECT 
    'DENY DELETE ON ' + t.NAME + ' TO (youruser)'
FROM sys.tables t
```

This will produce as its output (e.g. in SQL Server Management Studio) a list of statement to deny the `DELETE` permission from your user. Copy those rows into a text editor and remove those rows you don't need - and there you have your long list of `DENY` statements!

Comment: this will be for 1 table and i have more then 90 tables

Comment: ya but i want any other way to do so ,not writing 90 statements for 1 database , then for other database and so on....

Comment: @puneet: you can issue `DENY` for **all** tables, for a specific schema, or a specific table. You cannot do it any other way.

Comment: i have tables with same schema name and i don't want to deny permission to delete from all tables,

Comment: @puneet: well, then do `DENY DELETE ON (schemaname) TO (username)` for those schematas (one at a time) that you want to deny your user from